# How to plot multiindex accounting data with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

I attached screenshot of the data [sample data][1]

When I imported the csv, i set the index to be columns[0,1,2] The remaining columns [3: ] are dates ranging from 2015-07-31 to 2021-08-31.

My goal is to be able to create a plot based on 'Budget Name' and be able to drill down to 'Level 02' or 'Level 03'.

I want to create a line plot where the x-axis are the date columns and the y-axis are the values. However, what I attempted resulted in the x-axis being the 'Budget Code'.

The total data set has 17 items for budget name and each budget name has 'Level 02' and 'Level 03' data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# These are the first 30 rows of the csv file 
'Budget Code,Level 02,Level 03,2015-07-31,2015-08-31,2015-09-30,2015-10-31,2015-11-30,2015-12-31,2016-01-31,2016-02-29,2016-03-31,2016-04-30,2016-05-31,2016-06-30,2016-07-31,2016-08-31,2016-09-30,2016-10-31,2016-11-30,2016-12-31,2017-01-31,2017-02-28,2017-03-31,2017-04-30,2017-05-31,2017-06-30,2017-07-31,2017-08-31,2017-09-30,2017-10-31,2017-11-30,2017-12-31,2018-01-31,2018-02-28,2018-03-31,2018-04-30,2018-05-31,2018-06-30,2018-07-31,2018-08-31,2018-09-30,2018-10-31,2018-11-30,2018-12-31,2019-01-31,2019-02-28,2019-03-31,2019-04-30,2019-05-31,2019-06-30,2019-07-31,2019-08-31,2019-09-30,2019-10-31,2019-11-30,2019-12-31,2020-01-31,2020-02-29,2020-03-31,2020-04-30,2020-05-31,2020-06-30,2020-07-31,2020-08-31,2020-09-30,2020-10-31,2020-11-30,2020-12-31,2021-01-31,2021-02-28,2021-03-31,2021-04-30,2021-05-31,2021-06-30'
data = pd.read_csv(r'example_data.csv', index_col=[0,1,2]
data = data.fillna(0)
data.groupby('Budget Code').plot()
```

Is there a way to create this using pandas/seaborn/matplotlib ? The end result would be similar to a line plot in MS Excel. Thank`s`

Comment: Always provide a [mre], with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as text**. [SO Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/). It is likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and **add text**. Please see [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(30).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workable solution below. The aesthetics of the plots can certainly be improved.

```
noJune=data.drop(columns=['2016-06-30','2017-06-30','2018-06-30','2019-06-30','2020-06-30', 'Unnamed: 75'])
# Convert column names from strings to datetime
for i in range(3,len(noJune.keys())):
    noJune.rename(columns={noJune.keys([i]:datetime.datetime.strptime(noJune.keys()[i], '%Y-%m-%d')}, inplace=True)
```

Plot for the sum of all budget codes:

```
ax = noJune.sum(axis=0).T[3:70].plot(figsize=(30,15))
ax.set_xticks(noJune.keys()[3:70])
ax.grid(True)
```

Plot by budget code:

```
noJune.groupby('Budget Code').sum().T[3:70].plot(figsize=(30,50), subplots=True, x_compat=True)
```

Plot by GL account:

```
glPlot = noJune.groupby('Level 02').sum().T[3:70].plot(figsize=(30,50), subplots=True, x_compat=True)
```

Plot by sub-Gl:

```
detailPlot = noJune.groupby('Level 03').sum().T[3:70].plot(figsize=(30,50), subplots=True, x_compat=True)
```